# Magento 2.1 Admin grid not showing the disabled product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, admin, product-grid

Magento 2.1 admin catalog product grid didn't show the disabled product.

Comment: Please reindex and see.

Comment: as @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar suggested do reindex. Also, check if any enabled filter is applied to the grid. Most of the times people miss to notice that.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar I checked all above you mentioned, still not coming

Comment: in production or dev mode?

Comment: **developer**  mode

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I checked with core file, after adding the custom collection, the disabled product is coming but grid filter is not working.

Comment: Anyone, Please give a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Does the product show up if you search only for the SKU ? If so, the status might be different for a specific store view. Open the product in edit mode and check if *Status* had a checked *Use Default Value* for every store view.

I've noticed that the value shown in the overview doesn't mark values which have a different value per store view. This happens when you've set no store view filters, ie. show 'All store views'.